# Excel formula for recognizing months as a part of a specific year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, yearmonth

In Excel, if 2021 is the base year (year 1), and I am doing a financial model in terms of months (but would still like to know which year that month corresponds with), what formula can I use to say months 0-12 are year 1, months 13-24 are year 2, etc... I would like these to be on two separate rows to be able to easily see the year the month corresponds with.

I did a nested IF() function, but it's clunky and very manual.

```
=IF(G1<=12,1,IF(AND(G1>12,G1<=24),2,IF(AND(G1>24,G1<=36),3,IF(AND(G1>36,G1<=48),4,IF(AND(G1>48,G1<=60),5,IF(AND(G1>60,G1<=72),6,IF(AND(G1>72,G1<=84),7,IF(AND(G1>84,G1<=96),8,IF(AND(G1>96,G1<=108),9,IF(AND(G1>108,G1<=120),10,""))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Subtract 1
- integer/divide by 12
- add 1.

  ```
    =INT((G1-1)/12)+1
  ```

[image]